# automake gives the error ".la: file not recognized: file format not recognized"

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

I want to use a library created by libtool in an autoconf subproject but I get:

```bash
$ make
[...]
gcc  -g -O2   -o test test.o liba/liba.la 
liba/liba.la: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:417: test] Error 1
```

## Files

**configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([test], [1.0.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects])
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([liba])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = liba
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = test.c
test_LDADD = liba/liba.la
```

**test.c**

```
int main()
{
}
```

**liba/configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([liba], [1.0.0])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects])
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**liba/Makefile.am**

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
lib_LTLIBRARIES = liba.la
liba_la_SOURCES = liba.c
```

**liba/liba.c**

## Console

```bash
mkdir -p liba/m4 
autoreconf -i
[...]
./configure
[...]
make
[...]
gcc  -g -O2   -o test test.o liba/liba.la 
liba/liba.la: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:417: test] Error 1
```

It should be something like:

```
gcc  -g -O2   -o test test.o liba/.libs/liba.so
```

When I put the library and the program in the same autoconf/automake project it works but not if I use a sub project.

As workaroud it works if I use:
`test_LDADD = liba/.libs/liba.so`
but I think it's a workaround not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error just add LT_INIT in the configure.ac.

Comment: And as with all m4 macros which do not come with autoconf or automake, protect `LT_INIT` and put a `m4_pattern_forbid([^LT_INIT])dnl` in the line above the `LT_INIT` line. This prevents a silent error which produces a broken `configure` script in case the `libtool.m4` is not available when `configure` is generated.